# Disabling MySQL error messages

Tags: mysql, database, x-cart, mcafee

I have McAfee secure installed on my webserver . I am running Xcart on it.
The MCAfee shows me the following message

> During our analysis of your web application, we detected database
>   specific errors. By causing a system to output errors such as these,
>   it is often possible to determine the database version and inject
>   database command syntax that would allow us to extract data.
>
> The extent of the damage that can be caused by this vulnerability
>   varies greatly depending on environment and configuration. While input
>   validation via the web application may cause a database to "throw" an
>   error, the database configuration will also play an important role in
>   determining how much it can be altered. A remote attacker may be able
>   to gain access to very sensitive information, or gain administrative
>   access (total control of the entire database functionality). For
>   example, certain configurations of SQL server will allow one to create
>   user accounts with the ability to take control of the Windows server
>   that hosts the database.
>
> ### >
>
> **solution** is to turn off Database Error Messages from being displayed
>   back to the user. This is also not optimal and can lead to Blind SQL
>   Injection. Blind SQL Injection is still targeted by attackers and
>   drive-by worms. Please contact McAfee Secure Support if you need
>   further instructions.

MY question is from where can i Disable  this error message ? Where is the option to do it

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with php. Re-tagging.

Answer (score 3):

A much better solution would be to fix the error in the first place. Of course, without any code I can't tell you how to do that, but fixing errors is ALWAYS a better idea than sweeping them under the rug.

Comment: There is no error as such which appears on the server , its just MCafee which is showing me this a a vulnerability :)